# Race condition single-spa microapp mounting and angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, single-spa, single-spa-angular

I am having race condition using single-spa with Angular which result Single-Spa app rendered in just direct children of html root/body
for example I want to load Favorite micro app component under Header Component

```
 <body>
  <my-header>
      ...
      <div id="single-spa-application:user-favorite></div>
  </my-header>
 </body>
```

But it happens like 10% of time the microapp will load directly under body

```
<body>
 <my-header>...</my-header>
 <div id="single-spa-application:user-favorite></div>
</body>
```

I think the Single-Spa microapp activeWhen matches the url and load the app, for example /favorite and then active the micro app but the page (angular header component) is not ready yet (DOM is not complete), therefore the microapp was load outside .

I would love to know some insights and what are the best practices to avoid this condition.

Thank you

Comment: interesting, what if you wrap the div in `ng-container` ?

Comment: I have tried that since the single-spa app already active and the component is not yet ready, the microapp will go to root body...  ng-container didn't work for me.
this kind race condition and really depends on network time run time and render time. activeWhen URL met and the app will populate and it wont know if the page/component is ready or not.  That cause the issue.